# ember.js deploy on multiple servers

Tags: ember.js, deployment

I have three Amazon AWS instances on different regions and they are all linked to Route 53 and using Redis server to cache index.html.
I wanted to deploy my ember.js application on them all. Is it possible to have script to deploy to all of them in one step ?

Comment: Yes it is probably possible.

Comment: @iwin it would be appreciated if you tell me how can i approach that

Comment: @ShimaaMarzouk Can you provide more details about what you're AWS config? Right now this question is too broad for anyone to answer it. How do you do deployments right now?